# react-native array map modulus

Tags: arrays, react-native

So here's what I'm trying to achieve when mapping an array in react native:

```
<View>
<Image resizeMode='contain' style={[styles.myImage]} source={{uri: movie.image}} />
<Image resizeMode='contain' style={[styles.myImage]} source={{uri: movie.image}} />
</View>
```

Currently my array map is like so:

```
{this.state.titles.map(movie => (
<Image resizeMode='contain' style={[styles.myImage]} source={{uri: movie.image}} />
))}
```

How do I use modulus to add in an open/close View after multiples of 2 from my array?

Comment: why do you need this `View`? do you want to place every two images in a row? actually you want 2 item in each row?

Comment: Yes I'm placing 2 items in a row - the view is a container with flexDirection: row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To place every two `Images` in a row, I recommend you to use the `FlatList` component. `FlatList` is the best way to do this and this is recommended by `react-native` (look at [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html)). You can use it very simple and you can read its full document [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.47/docs/flatlist.html#flatlist). By using the `numColumns={2}` prop you define the number of items in each row.
Your code with `FlatList` would be like this:

```
  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => index;

  _renderItem = ({item: movie}) => (
    <Image resizeMode='contain' style={[styles.myImage]} source={{uri: movie.image}} />
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        data={this.state.titles}
        numColumns={2}
        extraData={this.state}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
      />
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Vahid - I'll have at this and report back.

Comment: OK so it's working apart from adding in numColumns={2}. Adding it renders the page blank - remove it and I have all images in one column

Comment: perhaps the width of each image is bigger than the `window.width/2`.

Comment: Yeah it was the styling I had from the previous solution. All fixed now - thanks again for your help Vahid.